# Shape Problem in Multivariate Normal using SciPy

Tags: python, scipy

I want to calculate the normal distribution given the mean, covariance, and some datapoints.

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
def calc_gamma(x, mu, sigma): 
    Gamma = multivariate_normal(x, mu, sigma)     
    return Gamma
```

now when I pass these values to the function, I get an error for the length of the mean.

```
test_data = np.array([[0, 0],[1,2]])
test_mu = np.array([[1, 1]])
test_sigma = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
test_gamma = calc_gamma(test_data, test_mus, test_sigmas)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19532\3211928287.py in <module>
      2 test_mus = np.array([[1, 1]])
      3 test_sigmas = np.array([[[1, 0], [0, 1]]])
----> 4 test_gamma_hat = calc_gamma_hat(test_data, test_pi, test_mus, test_sigmas)

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19532\3403511833.py in calc_gamma_hat(x, pi, mus, sigmas)
      1 def calc_gamma_hat(x,pi,mus, sigmas):
      2 
----> 3     Gamma = multivariate_normal(x,mus,sigmas)
      4     return Gamma
      5 

~\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_multivariate.py in __call__(self, mean, 
cov, allow_singular, seed)
    362         See `multivariate_normal_frozen` for more information.
    363         """
--> 364         return multivariate_normal_frozen(mean, cov,
    365                                           allow_singular=allow_singular,
    366                                           seed=seed)

~\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_multivariate.py in __init__(self, mean, 
cov, allow_singular, seed, maxpts, abseps, releps)
    730         """
    731         self._dist = multivariate_normal_gen(seed)
--> 732         self.dim, self.mean, self.cov = self._dist._process_parameters(
    733                                                             None, mean, cov)
    734         self.cov_info = _PSD(self.cov, allow_singular=allow_singular)

~\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_multivariate.py in 
_process_parameters(self, dim, mean, cov)
    405 
    406         if mean.ndim != 1 or mean.shape[0] != dim:
--> 407             raise ValueError("Array 'mean' must be a vector of length %d." %
    408                              dim)
    409         if cov.ndim == 0:

ValueError: Array 'mean' must be a vector of length 4.
```

Since I can't change the test values, any suggestions on why it does not work and how to "adjust" the function?

Comment: Compare your arguments (especially shape) to the documented requirements for multivariate_normal.

Comment: Note: `test_mus, test_sigmas` is not `test_mu, test_sigma`